# Copy a node from one XML tree to another XML tree in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

In SoapUI I want to use a Groovy script for picking a xml file from a directory, find a specific node tree in it and insert into a test request.

Let's consider the following file in my directory `res/001/data.xml` with the content

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:list>
         <ns:item attr1="yes">
             <title>Apple</title>
             <quant>3</quant>
         </ns:item>
         <ns:item attr1="no">
             <title>Banana</title>
             <quant>0</quant>
         </ns:item>
      </ns:list>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the soap request template:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:mylist/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I try to read the list into my request using XmlHolder in the script:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def xml
def req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SendData#Request" )
req.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://examle.com"

def folder = new File('res')

if (folder.exists())
{
    folder.eachDir( ) 
    { f ->
        def xmlfile = new File( f.absolutePath + "/data.xml")
        if( xmlfile.exists() )
        {
            def source = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( xmlfile.text )
            source.namespaces["ns2"] = "http://example.org"
            use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory)
            {
                for( item in source.getDomNodes( "//ns2:list/ns2:item" )) 
                {
                    log.info item.xml
                    req["//ns1:mylist[1]"].appendChild(item.xml)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

req.updateProperty()
```

My expected result would be:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:mylist>
         <ns:item attr1="yes">
             <title>Apple</title>
             <quant>3</quant>
         </ns:item>
         <ns:item attr1="no">
             <title>Banana</title>
             <quant>0</quant>
         </ns:item>
      </ns:mylist>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Question:** How can I achieve this?

My current solution gives an error because `req["//ns1:mylist[1]"]` is null. I have tried many different methods now bot none of them worked.

Comment: `example.com` and `example.org` namespaces are different on purpose?

Comment: Yes, the script should be namespace-aware.

Comment: You seem to be closing `<ns:item>` with a `</ns:list>`?

Comment: Thx @Carpetsmoker, my mistake while writing the minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @albciff !

My finally implemented solution is like this:

```groovy
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def xml
def req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SendData#Request" )
req.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://examle.com"
def parent = holder.getDomNode( "//ns1:myList[1]" )
def doc = parent.getOwnerDocument()

def folder = new File('res')

if (folder.exists())
{
    folder.eachDir( ) 
    { f ->
        def xmlfile = new File( f.absolutePath + "/data.xml")
        if( xmlfile.exists() )
        {
            def source = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( xmlfile.text )
            source.namespaces["ns2"] = "http://example.org"

            // I can modify things here like that:
            source["//ns2:list/item[1]/quant"] = "5"

            use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory)
            {
                for( item in source.getDomNodes( "//ns2:list/ns2:item" )) 
                {
                    def importNode = doc.importNode(item , true)
                    parent.appendChild( importNode )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

req.updateProperty()
```

*Please node: This minimal example was not tested.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `[]` notation which in `req` object is not working properly (I can't figure it out why) : `req["//ns1:mylist[1]"]` and also `req.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://examle.com"`.

Instead of use `[XPath]` try invoking the function explicitly with `getDomNode(XPath)` use also wildcard for namespaces instead of prefix because `namespaces["ns1"] = "http://example.com"` seems that also doesn't work as I said before (It's strange with `req` object doesn't work however with `source` object works properly).

At last with xmlbeans you can't add a node from another document directly, first you must import the node, so finally your code looks like (I tried and works for me with SOAPUI 5.0.0):

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def xml
def req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SendData#Request" )
//req.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://examle.com"

def folder = new File('res')

if (folder.exists())
{
    folder.eachDir( ) 
    { f ->
        def xmlfile = new File( f.absolutePath + "/data.xml")
        if( xmlfile.exists() )
        {
            def source = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( xmlfile.text )
            source.namespaces["ns2"] = "http://example.org"
            use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory)
            {
                for( item in source.getDomNodes( "//ns2:list/ns2:item" )) 
                {
                    log.info item.xml
                    // req["//ns1:mylist[1]"].appendChild(item.xml)
                    // CODE ADDED
                    def node = req.getDomNode("//*:mylist[1]");
                    def copyItem = node.getOwnerDocument().importNode(item,true);
                    node.appendChild(copyItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

req.updateProperty()
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much! This turned me into the right direction: Getting the DOM node and work with its "Owner Document". The way I implemented it: Receive the DOM note of the list, call importNode on the Soap-Request's OwnerDocument with it, receive the DOM node there and append it at the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

Here You've a working solution for replacing XML only (file processing omitted).

```
@Grab('xmlunit:xmlunit:1.5')

import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit

def xml = '''
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:list>
         <ns:item attr1="yes">
             <title>Apple</title>
             <quant>3</quant>
         </ns:item>
         <ns:item attr1="no">
             <title>Banana</title>
             <quant>0</quant>
         </ns:item>
      </ns:list>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'''

def tmpl = '''
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:mylist/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'''

def result = '''
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:mylist>
         <ns:item attr1="yes">
             <title>Apple</title>
             <quant>3</quant>
         </ns:item>
         <ns:item attr1="no">
             <title>Banana</title>
             <quant>0</quant>
         </ns:item>
      </ns:mylist>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'''

def soapNS = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 'soapenv')
def orgNS = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://example.org", 'ns')
def comNS = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://example.com", 'ns')
def source = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def target = new XmlParser().parseText(tmpl)

source[soapNS.Body][orgNS.list][0].each {
    def item = target[soapNS.Body][comNS.mylist][0].appendNode('ns:item', [attr1:it.@attr1])
    item.appendNode('title', it.title.text())
    item.appendNode('quant', it.quant.text())    
}

XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true)
XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true)
assert XMLUnit.compareXML(XmlUtil.serialize(target), XmlUtil.serialize(result))
```

In case of any questions feel free to ask.

P.S. The expected result in Your post isn't a valid XML file.